# Get paper size of the layer in autocad c#

Tags: .net, layout, size, autocad

I have a method that create a layout. I want to set the width and the height of the layout but I can't find this properties.

How to get and set the dimension of the layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call setCanonicalMediaName with the correct paper size available. Check the sample below

```
[CommandMethod("SetClosestMediaNameCmd")]
public void SetClosestMediaNameCmd()
{
    Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database db = doc.Database;
    Editor ed = doc.Editor;

    PlotSettingsValidator psv = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;

    // Let's first select the device
    StringCollection devlist = psv.GetPlotDeviceList();

    ed.WriteMessage("\n--- Plotting Devices ---");

    for (int i = 0; i < devlist.Count; ++i)
    {
        ed.WriteMessage("\n{0} - {1}", i+1, devlist[i]);
    }

    PromptIntegerOptions opts = new PromptIntegerOptions(
        "\nEnter device number: ");

    opts.LowerLimit = 1;
    opts.UpperLimit = devlist.Count;
    PromptIntegerResult pir = ed.GetInteger(opts);

    if(pir.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;

    string device = devlist[pir.Value - 1];

    PromptDoubleOptions pdo1 = new PromptDoubleOptions(
        "\nEnter Media Height(mm): ");

    PromptDoubleResult pdr1 = ed.GetDouble(pdo1);

    if (pdr1.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;

    PromptDoubleOptions pdo2 = new PromptDoubleOptions(
        "\nEnter Media Width(mm): ");

    PromptDoubleResult pdr2 = ed.GetDouble(pdo2);

    if (pdr2.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;

    using (Transaction Tx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        LayoutManager layoutMgr = LayoutManager.Current;

        Layout layout = Tx.GetObject(
            layoutMgr.GetLayoutId(layoutMgr.CurrentLayout),
            OpenMode.ForWrite)
                 as Layout;

        setClosestMediaName(
            psv, device, layout,
            pdr1.Value, pdr2.Value,
            PlotPaperUnit.Millimeters, true);

        Tx.Commit();
    }
}

void setClosestMediaName(PlotSettingsValidator psv,
    string device,
    Layout layout,
    double pageWidth,
    double pageHeight,
    PlotPaperUnit units,
    bool matchPrintableArea)   
{
    psv.SetPlotType(
        layout,
        Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Extents);

    psv.SetPlotPaperUnits(layout, units);
    psv.SetUseStandardScale(layout, false);
    psv.SetStdScaleType(layout, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);
    psv.SetPlotConfigurationName(layout, device, null);
    psv.RefreshLists(layout);

    StringCollection mediaList =
        psv.GetCanonicalMediaNameList(layout);

    double smallestOffset = 0.0;
    string selectedMedia = string.Empty;
    PlotRotation selectedRot = PlotRotation.Degrees000;

    foreach(string media in mediaList)
    {
        psv.SetCanonicalMediaName(layout, media);
        psv.SetPlotPaperUnits(layout, units);

        double mediaPageWidth = layout.PlotPaperSize.X;
        double mediaPageHeight = layout.PlotPaperSize.Y;

        if(matchPrintableArea)
        {
              mediaPageWidth  -=
                  (layout.PlotPaperMargins.MinPoint.X +
                   layout.PlotPaperMargins.MaxPoint.X);

              mediaPageHeight -=
                  (layout.PlotPaperMargins.MinPoint.Y +
                   layout.PlotPaperMargins.MaxPoint.Y);
        }

        PlotRotation rotationType = PlotRotation.Degrees090;

        //Check that we are not outside the media print area
        if(mediaPageWidth < pageWidth ||
           mediaPageHeight < pageHeight)
        {
              //Check if 90°Rot will fit, otherwise check next media
              if(mediaPageHeight < pageWidth ||
                 mediaPageWidth >= pageHeight)
              {
                    //Too small, let's check next media
                    continue;
              }

              //That's ok 90°Rot will fit
              rotationType = PlotRotation.Degrees090;
        }

        double offset = Math.Abs(
            mediaPageWidth * mediaPageHeight -
            pageWidth * pageHeight);

        if (selectedMedia == string.Empty || offset < smallestOffset)
        {
            selectedMedia = media;
            smallestOffset = offset;
            selectedRot = rotationType;

            //Found perfect match so we can quit early
            if (smallestOffset == 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    psv.SetCanonicalMediaName(layout, selectedMedia);
    psv.SetPlotRotation(layout, selectedRot);

    string localMedia = psv.GetLocaleMediaName(
        layout,
        selectedMedia);

    Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

    ed.WriteMessage("\n - Closest Media: " + localMedia);
    ed.WriteMessage("\n - Offset: " + smallestOffset.ToString());
    ed.WriteMessage("\n - Rotation: " + selectedRot.ToString());
}
```

Source: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/how-to-implement-plotsettingsvalidatorsetclosestmedianame-in-net.html

Comment: It helps a lot ! From the code, the dimension of the layout is as below:

width = layout.PlotPaperSize.X
height = layout.PlotPaperSize.Y